# Duvida na estrutura do código

Tags: javascript, algoritmo, react

Nesse codigo:

```
class ShoppingList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="shopping-list">
        <h1>Shopping List for {this.props.name}</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>Instagram</li>
          <li>WhatsApp</li>
          <li>Oculus</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Bom, minha duvida é:

o React.Component é uma classe?

O render () é um método?

e nesse aqui:

```
class Square extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: null,
    };
  }
```

o Constructor é um metodo?

O Props é um parametro??

E o super é uma função??

Pode parecer idiota essas perguntas mas estou tentando enteder ao maximo como funciona a estrutura da linguagem e do framework.

Ja li a documentação tanto do JS quanto do React porém ainda me perco um pouco

Comment: Tirando o caso dos props (que não sei bem como é passado pq não uso react), a resposta é sim pra todas as as perguntas.

Comment: Sim para todos... !!! estudou bem...

Answer (score 3):

Opa Matheus, boa parte dessas perguntas são em relação ao JS,

#### Constructor

É um tipo especial de método para criar e iniciar um objeto criado pela classe.

#### Super

Uma classe básica do `React` herda a classe `React.Component`, para passar parâmetros para a classe pai é necessário utilizar o método `super`, por isso ele é utilizado nesse caso, para passar as propriedades do componente para o pai da classe que é o `React.Component`.

#### Props

São as propriedades que o `React` recebe através das tags, abaixo um exemplo:

```
<Component title="Nome" />
```

Nesse exemplo acima, *title* é uma propriedade que vai vim nas `props` do `React`.

Answer (score 1):

> O `React.Component` é uma classe?

Sim, é uma classe. Como especificado na [API do React](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html), para criar um componente de classe, você **deve** extender a classe `Component`, exposta pelo React.

---

> O `render()` é um método?

Sim, é um método. No contexto do React, todos os componentes classe devem possuir um método [`render`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) para renderizar o HTML daquele componente.

Para saber mais sobre o funcionamento geral de métodos no JavaScript, veja a [documentação na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#M%C3%A9todos_Prot%C3%B3tipos).

---

> O `constructor` é um metodo?

Sim, é um método. Porém, especial. De acordo com a [documentação MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor), um construtor é um método especial para criar e inicializar um objeto criado a partir de uma classe, o que significa que sempre será executado quando a classe for instanciada.

No contexto do React, sempre que o componente for instanciado, o construtor será iniciado. Geralmente, isso só acontece **uma vez**.

---

> O `props` é um parametro?

Sim. Sempre que você renderiza um componente React, você tem a possibilidade de passar `props`, que poderão ser acessadas através do primeiro parâmetro do construtor da classe.

```js
<ListItem name="Estudar React" />
```

---

> O `super` é uma função?

**Não!** O [`super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) é uma palavra-chave do JavaScript usado para acessar a classe pai de uma classe.

No contexto do React, o `super` deve ser utilizado para passar as `props` para a classe pai `React.Component`.

Não entrarei em muitos detalhes sobre o porque dessa necessidade. Se você quiser, no entanto, saber mais sobre isso, recomendo a leitura do excelente artigo "[Por Que Nós Escrevemos super(props)?](https://overreacted.io/pt-br/why-do-we-write-super-props/)", do Dan Abramov.